# In Fullcalendar changing the buttonText to uppercase doesn't seem to stick when saving or running NPM run build

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I wanted to capitalize the button text on the right. When I go to the dist folder then to main.js. And change it here. When I save it it goes back to lowercase? In the global buttonText setting. Please look at the Image it shows where I make the change. But then when I save or run npm run build it goes back to lowercase :/ [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBzoM.png)

Is there a way to make changes and have them reflect when I open the index.html. It keep having to do npm run build each time I make a change.

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/buttonText - set it as an option in the configuration of your calendar instance, not by modifying the source code of fullCalendar

Comment: Where would this be located at? Can you give an example of setting it as an option in the configuration.

Comment: In what file would I find this piece of code? So I can modify it?

{
  today:    'today',
  month:    'month',
  week:     'week',
  day:      'day',
  list:     'list'
}

Comment: It would go in whatever file you declared your calendar. Somewhere you must have `new fullCalendar.Calendar` (or similar) containing all your options? ( As per the setup instructions: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/initialize-globals). Button text is an option, so declare it like all your other options

Answer (score 1):

Hope it helps

buttonText:{
today:    'Today',
month:    'Month',
week:     'Week',
day:      'Day',
listMonth: 'List Month',
listYear: 'List Year',
listWeek: 'List Week,
listDay: 'List Day'
}

here->https://fullcalendar.io/docs/buttonText